# Add Host Name to Output of Get-Datastore Command in PowerCLI

Tags: vmware, datastore, powercli

I guess its a pretty simple Problem.
I need to get the Free Disk Space and the Capacity of the Datastore of my VM Host

I really have no clue how i could add a Value which isnt naturally inculuded in the query i use, i am a noob in PowerCLI ^-^"

```
$disk = Get-VMHost| Get-Datastore | sort -Property FreeSpaceGB | sort -Property CapacityGB

$disk |out-file .\DiskStats.csv |out-null
```

This is What i get back:

```
Name                               FreeSpaceGB      CapacityGB
----                               -----------      ----------
Datastore                               28,125          39,750
```

But What i would need is more something like

```
Name                               FreeSpaceGB      CapacityGB
----                               -----------      ----------
HOSTNAME                            28,125          39,750
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? If you are using local storage with a 1:1 or even many:1 datastore:host relationship, then why not name your storage volumes accordingly? Like `Hostname7-volume2` or whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to just add an expression in a foreach loop.

```
    $disk =""

     Foreach ($esihost in get-vmhost)
     {

      $disk +=   $esihost |get-datastore |select @{name="ESXi;e={$esihost}}, 
      name, FreeSpaceGB, CapacityGB
      }
```